# Silverlight xap file not being copied to ClientBin on Build Server

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, msbuild, build-process

We're developing a ASP.Net Web Application project that has a Silverlight 2.0 component. We've referenced the silverlight project in the web application properties, and the xap file is being copied to the ClientBin folder of the Web application when we build locally.

The problem is that when we build this on our build server (which is using CruiseControl.Net, though I don't think that's relevant) the xap file isn't being copied. The strange thing is that this was working, but something has broken it and we can't figure out what.

Anybody seen this before?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sorted!

Not quite sure why, but it turns out we had an out-of-date version of Microsoft.WebApplications.targets on the build server - the version we had didn't have the *CopySilverlightApplications* task in it. To fix the problem, I copied the two files from the `C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v9.0\WebApplications` folder to the same location on the build server. Now everything works as it should.

Now if only I could find out which installer should have updated those files...

Comment: The same has happened for me. This is with VS2008SP1 and I used the Web Platform installer to download and install "Silverlight 3 Tools for Visual Studio", "Silverlight Toolkit (october)" and "WCF Ria Services". 

For some reason, this worked well on one machine and failed on another. The exact same procedure. There were slight differences in the existing configuration, so I think one of those differences broke the installer.

Anyway, thanks for updating with your success.

Comment: The two files that need to be copied are "Microsoft.WebApplication.Build.Tasks.Dll" and "Microsoft.WebApplications.targets".

These files are added by the Visual Studio 2008 Web Deployment extensions installer. Copying them manually to the build server is a hack necessary (I think) because this installer won't run unless VS 2008 is installed and few people want the IDE installed on their build server.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following tag in my project file fixed it:

```
<VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
```

e.g.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
</PropertyGroup>
<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="false" />
```

Maybe VSToolsPath is set before this point on my local machine, but not on the build server.

Comment: That worked for me, but I also needed to check everything that looked like a version number throughout the project file.  In my case I had to change a couple instances of `v10.0` and `12.0` to `14.0` to get an old project to work on my VS2015 install.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar issue where some files weren't being built/moved to my dev server. The issue ended up being permission as I manually deleted a folder. For some reason, the Network Service account and permissions weren't being inherited by the newly recreated folder.